# xna button touch location

Tags: c#, xna

In my Xna game I have 3 game states(menu,levels,playing).When I am clicking a button in menu,it is directly going to playing gamestate.I know the reason ,as there is a button in levels gamestate in same position like in button in menu.Below is the code in menu

```
TouchCollection touchCollection1 = TouchPanel.GetState();
                    foreach (TouchLocation location in touchCollection1)
                    {
                        if (btnStart.rectangle.Contains((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y) && isPlayDrawn==true)
                        {
                            gameState = state.levels;
                        }

                    }
```

bellow is the code in levels-

```
TouchCollection touchCollection1 = TouchPanel.GetState();
                    foreach (TouchLocation location in touchCollection1)
                    {
                        if (btnLEvel.rectangle.Contains((int)location.Position.X, (int)location.Position.Y) && isPlayDrawn==true)
                        {
                            gameState = state.playing;
                        }
}
```

Could you please show me some direction on this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a video on Game States which is very good explanation.

You can add a mouse state and just make sure that two states are different before you perform the action, i.e check and make sure the mouse last state was pressed and current state is up. Then perform the action.

Good luck!

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTxdOWC_Ytc

Comment: Will it work if I am placing different  textures in same position

Comment: Yes it will, because it is checking for a mouse state you should only execute the statement when the last state was mouse Up and the position was over it.. Made a mistake in my last reply, try it out what do you have to lose.